# How to include missing files while compiling and installing bioconductor packages?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm trying to install biocneighbors from bioconductor. Unfortunately I recieve the following error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘BiocNeighbors’ ...
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R/" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/m3hdad/R/Rcpp/include" -
ric -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -c annoy_stubs.cpp -o annoy_stub
In file included from annoy_stubs.cpp:2:
annoy.h:13:10: fatal error: annoylib.h: No such file or directory
 #include "annoylib.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I do not understand if I have to provide the file for the algorithm "annoy" or it should be included in the source code.
I am using Arch linux.

Answer (score 0):

That would be [RcppAnnoy](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppAnnoy) for which I am maintainer.

And [BiocNeighbors](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/BiocNeighbors.html) has a `LinkingTo:` on it as it should.

So something is wrong/weird at your end as *every* `LinkingTo:` turns to a `-I...` as we see *e.g.* in your quote on the other `LinkingTo:` it has -- for Rcpp.

Comment: I did not quite understand if there is something I need to do to get it working.

Comment: Well it works for everybody else, including the BioC regression tests.  For starters, do you have RcppAnnoy installed?